# Why does QComboBox ignore its fixed vertical size policy?

Tags: qt

I have a widget with two stacked layers. The first looks like this, which is fine:

[image]

The second looks like this, which is wrong.

[image]

Here is complete code which produces the widget and prints the size policies.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    auto stack = new QStackedWidget ();
    QWidget * labelbox = new QWidget ();
    QWidget * combobox = new QComboBox ();
    QWidget * label = new QLabel ("Label");
    QWidget * button = new QPushButton ("Button");
    QWidget * date = new QDateTimeEdit ();

    auto gl = new QGridLayout (& w);
    auto hl = new QHBoxLayout (labelbox);

    hl -> addWidget (label);
    hl -> addWidget (button);

    stack -> addWidget (labelbox);
    stack -> addWidget (combobox);
    stack -> setCurrentIndex (1); // 0 is the good layer, 1 is the bad

    gl -> addWidget (date);
    gl -> addWidget (stack, 0, 1);

    w .setMinimumSize (300, 200);
    w .show ();

    for (auto x : {(QWidget *) stack, labelbox, combobox, label, button, date})
    {
        qWarning ()
            << x -> metaObject () -> className ()
            << x -> sizePolicy ();
    }
    return app .exec ();
}
```

The stdout is as follows:

```
QStackedWidget QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 5, verticalPolicy = 5)
QWidget        QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 5, verticalPolicy = 5)
QComboBox      QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 5, verticalPolicy = 0)
QLabel         QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 1, verticalPolicy = 5)
QPushButton    QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 1, verticalPolicy = 0)
QDateTimeEdit  QSizePolicy(horizontalPolicy = 1, verticalPolicy = 0)
```

The documentation for these values is:

```
QSizePolicy::Fixed      = 0 The QWidget::sizeHint() is the only acceptable alternative, so the widget can never grow or shrink (e.g. the vertical direction of a push button).
QSizePolicy::GrowFlag   = 1 The widget can grow beyond its size hint if necessary.
QSizePolicy::ExpandFlag = 2 The widget should get as much space as possible.
QSizePolicy::ShrinkFlag = 4 The widget can shrink below its size hint if necessary.
QSizePolicy::IgnoreFlag = 8 The widget's size hint is ignored. The widget will get as much space as possible.
```

So it looks like the vertical size policies are `Fixed` except for the `QStackedWidget`, the `QWidget` which contains the label and button, and the `QLabel`, which all have `GrowFlag|ShrinkFlag`.

Why does the `QComboBox` grow vertically, despite its `Fixed` policy?
Why does this not happen to the `QPushButton` or the `QDateTimeEdit`?

This happens with Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.1 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Because `QComboBox` default vertical size policy is not `Fixed`. You can set necessary size policy, if you want.

Comment: The stdout clearly shows that it is `Fixed`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mixed up horizontalPolicy and verticalPolicy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the combo box directly to the QStackedWidget but haven't added it to a QLayout first. Assign it to a layout, add this layout to a QWidget and then add this QWidget to the QStackedWidget.

Example:

```
QWidget * combowidget = new QWidget ();
QWidget * combobox = new QComboBox ();

auto vl = new QVBoxLayout (combowidget);

vl->addWidget(combobox);
stack->addWidget (combowidget);
```

Comment: That worked, but it's very surprising. Doesn't QComboBox manage its own internal layout? Why is the intermediate widget necessary? Thanks.

Comment: The size policies are only relevant if that QWidget has been added to a layout. QComboBox would itself need to be added to a layout as otherwise the size policy is ignored. Usually as a matter of course you add a QWidget to a layout instead of directly to the parent widget but because QStackedWidget works a bit differently you add the widget directly. I've ran into the same issue before.

Comment: @spraff "Doesn't QComboBox manage its own internal layout?" It does. But you still need someone to manage combo box's position and size - its exterior, so to speak. The stacked widget simply filly expands the widget and that's not what you want. "Why is the intermediate widget necessary?" It's necessary so that you can have a layout that respects combo box's size limits. It's a design decision of the stacked widget: it keeps all widgets the same size.